# Shorthand to declaring empty object properties in Javascript, is there any?

Tags: javascript, object, properties

I need to declare a lot of object properties in my script and I wonder if the're any way to shorten this:

```
Core.registry.taskItemSelected;
Core.registry.taskItemSelected.id;
Core.registry.taskItemSelected.name;
Core.registry.taskItemSelected.parent;
Core.registry.taskItemSelected.summary;
Core.registry.taskItemSelected.description;
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Wouldn't that work?

```
Core.registry.taskItemSelected = {
  id: null,
  name: null,
  parent: null,
  ...
};
```

Comment: Is there any way to leave out the null  and go like: Core.registry.taskItemSelected = {id, name, parent...};
Or would this just create a numerated properties with empty values?

Comment: Wouldn't be shorter `0` inseatd of `null`? Because formally you would use `undefined`

Comment: `0` might not be "an empty value". Perhaps `void 0`?

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work:

```
var props = ["id", "name", "parent", ...];
Core.registry.taskItemSelected = {};
for (var i = 0; i < props.length; i++)
   Core.registry.taskItemSelected[props[i]] = "";
```

Edit: following the OP comments, here is better version with same final result:

```
Object.prototype.declare = function (varArray) {
    for (var i = 0; i < varArray.length; i++) {
        this[varArray[i]] = {};
    }
};

//usage:
var props = ["id", "name", "parent"];
Core = {};
Core.declare(props);
```

And live test case as well: http://jsfiddle.net/5fRDc/

Comment: Can I just extend the Object object with your function by doing  Object.prototype.declare = function ... and have it accept an array like var props = [....]. I might then go like Core.registry.taskItemSelected.declare(props) How would I go about setting the properties in the right object?? Using this

Comment: Sorry @Edward but I'm not (yet) familiar with those things.. but feel free to try it and in case it works let me know.

Comment: @Edward You could, but you may want to check out [Object.create](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create) and [Object.defineProperties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperties) instead

Comment: @Shadow Wizard All ideas help (Itried it out, it actually works), thanx.

Comment: @Zecc Will look into Object.create and Object.defineProperties!

Comment: var props = ["id", "name", "parent"];

Object.prototype.declare = function (varArray) {
 for (var i = 0; i < varArray.length; i++) {
    this[varArray[i]] = {};
 }
}
Core = {};
Core.declare(props);